# PCL Point Cloud Library converting from abstract PointT to PointXYZ pcl::PointCloud<PointType>::ConstPtr to pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>

Tags: point-cloud-library

My callback function called cloud_cb takes a parameter of type `pcl::PointCloud<PointType>::ConstPtr`.

But I cannot figure out for the life of me how to convert the data to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`.

Answer (score 0):

`PointType` is not a PCL point type, it is a template parameter that can represent `pcl::PointXYZ` or any other PCL data type (if you are using a sample code, look for a `typedef` somewhere).

`pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr`
is a pointer, namely a Boost shared pointer (see doc [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm))

while
`pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`
is the pointee your shared pointer points to

So make sure that your `PointType` is `pcl::PointXYZ` and if it is, you can use the boost pointer similarly to a regular pointer.